# C++17 How is the vector class deducing the type from parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, types, constructor, variadic

i would like to deduce class type from parameter pack passed to constructor (assuming all values in the parameter pack are the same type), is it possible?

```
template<class T>
class SomeClass {
public:
   template<typename... Args>
   SomeClass(Args... args)
   {}

    std::vector<T> value;
}

int main() {
    SomeClass someClass(10, 40, 50, 60) // T would be int
}
```

How can i deduce T from Args???

Answer (score 2):

You might provide custom deduction guide (C++17), something like:

```
template <typename... Ts>
SomeClass(Ts...) -> SomeClass<std::common_type_t<Ts...>>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f464007b67eca8)

Answer (score 1):

Under what you have you cannot as the vector is a member and members can only be based on parameters to the enclosing type.

You could however make the vector a member of some other type (including a type contained by SomeClass) and then do some really ugly work with type erasure (for illustration only, I have not tried adding this to what you have and getting it to compile). And note that all of the following code would go inside SomeClass:

```
struct base
{
```

virtual ~base() {}
virtual Type & get_item(size_t index) = 0;
};
template
struct impl : base
{
std::vector values.

```
  Type & get_item(sze_t index)
  {
    return values[index];
  };
};

std::unique_ptr<base> holder;

template<typename ... Types>
SomeClass(Types ... t)
  : base{std::make_unique<impl<std::common_type_t<Types...>>>(std::forward<Types>(t))}
{
}
}

Type & get_item(size_t index)
{
  return holder->get_item(index);
}
```